# ERROR 1115 (42000) at line 29: Unknown character set: 'utf32'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to import a mysqldump file into my local database. I am using the following command

```
mysql5 -u root -p fbpj < anthonyl_fbpj.sql
```

and the following error appears

```
ERROR 1115 (42000) at line 29: Unknown character set: 'utf32'
```

__
Below is the part of the dump where the error is being thrown, at the very bottom. I am confused on what could be going on.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.11.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 02, 2013 at 03:49 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.23
-- PHP Version: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `anthonyl_fbpj`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `comments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `task_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `data_type_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `data_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_comments_users` (`user_id`),
  KEY `fk_comments_projects1` (`project_id`),
  KEY `fk_comments_data_types1` (`data_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;
```

Comment: MySQL added support for UTF32 **very** late, what's your version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your table `comments` is set to use the `UTF32` character set, which was not supported by MySQL before [v5.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html).

You are probably attempting to import this dump into an earlier version of MySQL.

You might be able to get away with it just by changing `utf32` to `utf8` in your dump, before loading it.